# Is it possible to tie the Graphic which I drawn with action listener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I drawn some rectangle, using Graphic g.

Is it possible that I use the rectangle I drawn and tie it with some code. So that when I click on that rectangle. Some action happen.

Answer (score 3):

Of course. If you use java's [rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) there is are methods called `intersects` and `contains`. If you use a [MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) you can listen for mouse clicks and know the coordinates where the user clicked.

After setting the mouselistener up, you can simply check if the rectangle contains the mouse and is clicked:

```
if(mouse.isClicked() && rect.contains(mouse.x, mouse.y) { //do stuff }
```

I hope you get the basic picture.